# Ошибка TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Писал код для погодного тг бота и при попытке написать что-то боту в pycharm вылазит ошибка что написана в заголовке.

Вот код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import python_weather

# bot init
bot = Bot(token="Тут токен")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
client = python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL)

# echo
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    weather = await client.find(message.text)
    celsius = round((weather.current.temperature - 32) / 1.8)

    resp_msg = weather.location_name + "\n"
    resp_msg += f"Текущая температура: {celsius}\n"
    resp_msg += f"Состояние погоды: {weather.current.sky_text}"

    if celsius <= 10:
        resp_msg += "\n\nПрохладно!"
    else:
        resp_msg += "\n\nТепло!"

    await message.answer(resp_msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: На какой строке ошибка? `weather = await client.find(message.text)` или `await message.answer(resp_msg)`? Выведите в консоль объекты `client` и `message`, посмотрите какой из них `None`

Comment: weather = client.find(message.text)

Comment: Ошибка на строке weather = await client.find(message.text)